# Where Visual studio referencing 'System.ServiceModel.Security and resulting in error

Tags: asp.net-core, wcf, asp.net-core-mvc

I am integrating the class library project into an ASP.NET Core 6 application (Client application).
The reference is made by the ASP.NET application and can see the classes and methods but throws the below error from the class library project.
I have installed runtime .net framework 4.8.1

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.ServiceModel.Security, Version=4.8.1.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file
> specified.'

In the class library References tab System.ServiceModel.Security is available but checking the Runtime version shows v4.0.30319 and the version shows 4.0.0.0.

I am unable to proceed.
Please experts help.

[image: Error]

```
            Imports System.ServiceModel
            Imports System.ServiceModel.Channels
            Imports System.ServiceModel.Security
            Imports System.Xml
            Imports System.Runtime.Serialization


            Public NotInheritable Class GlobalProperties

                Public Shared Function ServiceBinding() As CustomBinding

                    Dim binding As New CustomBinding()
                    binding.Name = "customBinding"

                    Dim security = TransportSecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement()
                    security.EnableUnsecuredResponse = True
                    security.AllowInsecureTransport = True
                    security.IncludeTimestamp = False
                    security.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256
                    security.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10

                    Dim encoding = New TextMessageEncodingBindingElement()
                    encoding.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap11
                    encoding.WriteEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8

                    Dim transport = New HttpTransportBindingElement()
                    transport.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Integer.MaxValue
                    transport.MaxBufferSize = Integer.MaxValue
                    transport.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard

                    encoding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = Convert.ToInt64(16384)
                    encoding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 32
                    encoding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = Convert.ToInt64(8192)
                    encoding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = Convert.ToInt64(4096)
                    encoding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = Convert.ToInt64(16384)

                    binding.Elements.Add(security)
                    binding.Elements.Add(encoding)
                    binding.Elements.Add(transport)

                    binding.CloseTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 1, 0)
                    binding.OpenTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 1, 0)
                    binding.ReceiveTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 10, 0)
                    binding.SendTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 2, 0)

                    Return binding

                End Function

            End Class
```

Comment: Try to add `System.ServiceModel.Security` through Nuget packages in the class library

Comment: Why you add the old .net framework inside the asp.net core? If possible, please migrate the old .net method to the asp.net core method instead of using the .net inside the asp.net core

Comment: Thank you @BrandoZhang. Its old .net framework class library project. We configured webservices wsdl files. We used custom binding please  refer the my post above ,i have edited and pasted the code. Now this code has to be migrated to .net core. i am getting the error from this module only.